# How to make a facebook query to get a post between 2 dates?

Tags: javascript, facebook

I got a login and simple /me/home but "until" does not seem to work.

If I go before a month data comes with no thing.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to look up a post between certain dates as the `/user/home` edge does not contain a valid field for a date or time.

Comment: If I use 14143500000 as until it gives me back data but anything before 1400350000